# is there parallelism inside Ollama?

Tags: python, docker, mistral-7b, ollama

I wrote a Python program to translate large English texts into French. What I do is feed a bunch of reports to [Ollama](https://github.com/ollama/ollama) using a for loop.

```
from functools import cached_property

from ollama import Client


class TestOllama:

    @cached_property
    def ollama_client(self) -> Client:
        return Client(host=f"http://127.0.0.1:11434")

    def translate(self, text_to_translate: str):
        ollama_response = self.ollama_client.generate(
            model="mistral",
            prompt=f"translate this French text into English: {text_to_translate}"
        )
        return ollama_response['response'].lstrip(), ollama_response['total_duration']

    def run(self):
        reports = ["reports_text_1", "reports_text_2"....] # avearge text size per report is between 750-1000 tokens.
        for each_report in reports:
            try:
                translated_report, total_duration = self.translate(
                    text_to_translate=each_report
                )
                print(f"Translated text:{translated_report}, Time taken:{total_duration}")
            except Exception as e:
                pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    job = TestOllama()
    job.run()
```

docker command to run ollama:

```
docker run -d --gpus=all --network=host --security-opt seccomp=unconfined -v report_translation_ollama:/root/.ollama --name ollama ollama/ollama
```

My question is, when I run this script on V100 and H100, I don't see a significant difference of execution time, and also I have avoided parallelism by thinking perhaps Ollama internally uses parallelism to process, but I only see one core that is working with htop command. Am I right on this matter?

I am a beginner in NLP; any help/guidance would be appreciated, in order me to organize my code (e.g: use multithreading to send Ollama requests…etc)

Comment: Do you have a GPU in your machine? GPU parallelization != CPU parallelization

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Yeah, I understand that part. What I don't understand is H100 suppose to be better than V100, but I don't see a difference.

Comment: Oh hang on! `reports` is an empty list. Neither H100 nor V100 is actually doing anything since your `for each_report in reports` loop doesn't actually execute

Comment: @inspectorG4dget sorry for the confusion. I just wrote the above code for Stack Overflow as an example. I just put reports array as an example.

Comment: You'll need to make sure that your underlying Python dependencies have GPU support enabled, and/or that your OS has the applicable drivers/SDK tools installed.

Comment: ok fair enough. Could you please clarify whether the entries in `reports` are representative? More specifically: are your actual inputs also comparably small? If so, it might just be that your inputs are small enough to not highlight the performance difference between V100 and H100

Comment: @inspectorG4dget texts are between 750 and 1000 tokens.

Comment: @tadman I had installed NVIDIA CUDA drivers and toolkits.

Comment: The next step is to check that they're actually being used, and that it isn't defaulting to CPU-only.

Comment: I gave you links to tools you could use for that purpose (checking if your GPU is actually used) in comments on your previous, now-deleted copy of this question. (Why did you delete and recreate it instead of editing it?)

Comment: GPUs are implicitly very parallel devices; they basically don't do any non-parallelized work at all. There are also parts of processing LLM results that can only be done on the CPU, and how well _those_ are parallelized by ollama is a legitimate implementation question, but the question of "is it using all of the GPU resources that can be used?" is very probably yes _if it's correctly installed and using your GPU at all_, which right now is a question you're providing no evidence for or against either way.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, I think GPU is on the use, because when I tested this on a CPU, it took on average 3 minutes to translate a text (750–1000 tokens) and in the V100 it takes on average 3 seconds, but I don't see a difference between the V100, H100, and 2xV100. Thank you!

Comment: That does make it sound like the decoding -- happening on CPU -- isn't parallelized by ollama, and like _that's_ your bottleneck once you get a fast enough GPU.

Comment: ...mind, whether decoding _can_ be parallelized for a given model has a lot to do with the architecture of that particular model (whether it's multi-head, f/e), not just the software you're using to _run_ the model. (There are other cases like beam search where you can require multiple decoding steps and run _those_ in parallel, but that's inherently more resource-intensive than only following one branch even though it improves output quality).

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, till now (2024 March 29), ollama doesn't support parallelization.

Since you have two GPUs, you could try running two or more (not recommended) ollama containers at different ports. Here is an [example](https://github.com/ParisNeo/ollama_proxy_server).

OK, I shall make my answer self-contained. Here are certain steps for u:

1. Pull the offical ollama image from dockerhub:
   `docker pull ollama/ollama:latest`
2. Run the 1st docker container using

   ```bash
   docker run -d \
   --gpus=0 \
   -v {the_dir_u_save_models}:/root/.ollama \
   -p {port1}:11434 \
   --name ollama \
   ollama/ollama
   ```
3. Run the 2nd docker container using

   ```bash
   docker run -d \
   --gpus=1 \
   -v {the_dir_u_save_models}:/root/.ollama \
   -p {port2}:11434 \
   --name ollama \
   ollama/ollama
   ```

   Watch out the difference in `--gpus=` and `-p` parameters.
4. use async to manage your parallelization logic in Python or other languages. Here are some pesudo-code describing the process:

   ```js
   function processQuestionsAsync(questions) {
       // Sort questions based on a specific criterion, e.g., LLM
       questions.sort((a, b) => {
           // Example: sorting by 'LLM'. Adjust comparison logic as needed.
           return a.LLM.localeCompare(b.LLM);
       });

       // Divide questions into two batches
       let batch1 = questions.slice(0, questions.length / 2);
       let batch2 = questions.slice(questions.length / 2);

       // Initialize an array to collect responses
       let responses = [];

       // Function to send questions to a server asynchronously
       async function sendToServer(batch, serverURL) {
           for (let question of batch) {
               let response = await sendQuestionToServer(question, serverURL);
               // Once a response is received, send it to the front-end
               sendResponseToFrontEnd(response);
               // Store response in the responses array
               responses.push(response);
           }
       }

       // Define server URLs for each batch
       let serverURL1 = "http://server1.com/api";
       let serverURL2 = "http://server2.com/api";

       // Use Promise.all to handle both batches in parallel
       Promise.all([
           sendToServer(batch1, serverURL1),
           sendToServer(batch2, serverURL2)
       ]).then(() => {
           // All questions have been processed, and all responses have been sent to the front-end
           console.log("All questions processed");
       }).catch(error => {
           // Handle errors
           console.error("An error occurred:", error);
       });
   }

   // Function to simulate sending a question to a server
   async function sendQuestionToServer(question, serverURL) {
       // Simulate network request
       let response = await fetch(serverURL, {
           method: 'POST',
           body: JSON.stringify(question),
           headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
           },
       });

       // Return the response data
       return await response.json();
   }

   // Function to simulate sending a response back to the front-end
   function sendResponseToFrontEnd(response) {
       console.log("Sending response to front-end:", response);
   }

   // Example usage with questions as objects including 'contentType'
   let questions = [
       { question: "What is 2+2?", contentType: "Math", LLM: "GPT-3" },
       { question: "What is the capital of France?", contentType: "Geography", LLM: "GPT-3" },
       { question: "What is the largest ocean?", contentType: "Geography", LLM: "GPT-4" },
       { question: "What is the speed of light?", contentType: "Physics", LLM: "GPT-3" }
   ];
   processQuestionsAsync(questions);
   ```

The pesudo-code above doesn't matter. The most important thing is that u may receive requests from front-end asking for different LLMs, and one ollama instance has to onload and offload between them. Try to avoid this as far as possible.

By the way, based on my own experience with ollama on A100, parallelization may not be a good choice. VRAM is abundant for sure, but the computing capacity is always limited.

Comment: Because links can go dead, and answers on SO need to be self-contained, please update your answer to include an example that does not rely solely on a link. Thanks